# Filter on the list of facet values

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I have a 'keywords' field in my index, which is Facetable, and of type Collection(Edm.String).

In my UI I show a facet for this fields which returns the top 10 keywords.
The total number of distinct keywords value may be many hundreds.
So I would like the user to be able to enter a term, and the top 10 facet values containing this term would be returned.
So this is kind of filtering the list of facet values for a field.

Is this currently possible with Azure Search API ?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not supported. It's possible to filter the set of documents returned, which will influence the facets that are returned, but there is no way to directly filter the facet values themselves using a search expression or "contains" semantics.

You could filter on your keywords field, but then you'd only get the matching facet value, not the top 10 facet values that contain a search term.